# Using libcurl to write HTTPS SOAP client

Tags: c++, c, soap, https, libcurl

I have been using libcurl to do a little webscraping and now I want to use it to write a HTTPS client. I am fine using libcurl so far by implementing the write_data() callback functions to write the received data to file (as explained in the libcurl tutorials). The thing I was wondering is that is it possible to get the server response from a char buffer, or set things up so that the response gets written to a char buffer?? Reading the response from a file is not the end of the world but it would just be much easier if I could get it straight from memory and parse the xml immediately. I have done a fair bit of searching both here and on the web in general but I have yet to find anything and thought I would ask here in case there is a 'trick' to getting what I want. I would guess not but I thought it was worth asking the question anyway.

**Edit:** I am writing this in C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like the [getinmemory.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) example that downloads the data and keeps it in a malloc'ed buffer?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted - I have been looking for something like that for days now. Many thanks!!